# Child Form's MDI Parent Property Becomes Null in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdiparent

I'm a 13-year-old learning C# and I've come across an issue in my Windows Forms application. The MDI parent property of a child form becomes null after adding it to a panel. Below is the relevant code snippet:

```cs
public void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, object btnSender)
{
    previousForm = null;
    ActivateButton(btnSender);
    if (activeForm != null)
        activeForm.Close();
    childForm.MdiParent = this;
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.panelDesktopPane.Controls.Add(childForm);
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
    lblTitle.Text = childForm.Text;
}
```

After dynamically adding a child form to a panel, I've noticed that its MDI parent property becomes null, resulting in unexpected behavior
by adding breakpoints i found out that the mdiparent property becomes null right after the form is added to panelDesktopPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you’re facing is due to the fact that a Form cannot be both an MDI child and a control on a Panel at the same time. When you add the form to the Panel’s controls, it ceases to be an MDI child and its MdiParent property becomes null.

Removing the following line from your code should solve the problem:

```
childForm.MdiParent = this;
```

Comment: but i want it to be a mdi child and be inside the panel
Is there any way to have it so

Comment: If added to a control, it will have its `Parent` property set instead. Weifen Luo's [DocakPanelSuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DockPanelSuite) may also be useful for such things (e.g. to dock a tool window).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes i dont understand could u please elaborate for a beginner

Comment: I don't know what you want to do exactly, but since you are adding a form to a panel, I assumed that maybe you want to achieve something like in Visual Studio where you can dock different windows (document windows, property windows, error windows, etc.) where you want them to be. This is what the DockPanelSuite allows you to do wihtout MDI forms. You can even detach a window completely and make it floating. See the [images here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) (but use the other link, if you want to install it or use NuGet from within Visual Studio).